# Send mass email to contacts whose accounts have certain type of contracts

Tags: salesforce

In Salesforce, both contacts and contracts are related to accounts but not directly to each other.

How can I send mass email to contacts whose accounts have certain type of contracts only?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should be able to write a SOQL query that walks the two levels of the relationships.

Comment: How many emails are you envisaging? Note that Salesforce doesn't really support mass mail-outs and has imposed limits — you may need to integrate with a third party solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is a mass email based on contacts leads, and its limited to 1000 emails per day org wide. We had a similar requirement but unfortunately the mass email filter is not that powerful that you can query into account's contracts. The formula field also didn't help. The solution we implemented was a trigger on contract and contact which updated all account's contacts' custom field when the condition was satisfied. Then we used that field as a filter for mass email.